# Mathematics of Yang-Mills theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I am looking for a preferable introductory text on **Yang-Mills theory** in differential forms language.

I have searching for a rigorous definition of this theory on Manifolds for mathematicians. Physics book that I have seen so far do not go through details. So I am asking for good references qualifying these properties.

It would be very nice to hearing from you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some resources on Yang-Mills theory:

- [Applications of differential geometry to physics](https://sgielen.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/diffgeo.pdf)
- [Geometric foundations of classical Yang-Mills theory](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4296/1/Geometric_Foundations_of_Classical_Yang-Mills_Theory_-_Catren.pdf)
- [Quantum Yang-Mills theory](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/yangmills.pdf)
- [Geometry of gauge fields (Springer)](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783319297323-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1600309-p179526593)
- [Yang-Mills theory and geometry](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~skdona/YMILLS.PDF)

While going through some of these papers, consider skimming through some of their references also.